# terraform aws_acm_certificate_validation.cert_api: Still creating... [4m21s elapsed] until timeout

Tags: terraform-provider-aws

The ACM Certificate Validation never completes, it times out after about 45 mins, looking at the AWS Hosted Zone for the domain, it has a cname record.  It never reaches the create the Api Gateway Domain section.

main.tf

```
resource "aws_acm_certificate" "cert_api" {
  domain_name       = var.api_domain
  validation_method = "DNS"

  tags = {
    Name = var.api_domain
  }
}

resource "aws_acm_certificate_validation" "cert_api" {
  certificate_arn         = aws_acm_certificate.cert_api.arn
  validation_record_fqdns = aws_route53_record.cert_api_validations.*.fqdn
}


resource "aws_route53_zone" "api" {
  name = var.api_domain
}

resource "aws_route53_record" "cert_api_validations" {
  allow_overwrite = true
  count           = length(aws_acm_certificate.cert_api.domain_validation_options)

  zone_id = aws_route53_zone.api.zone_id
  name    = element(aws_acm_certificate.cert_api.domain_validation_options.*.resource_record_name, count.index)
  type    = element(aws_acm_certificate.cert_api.domain_validation_options.*.resource_record_type, count.index)
  records = [element(aws_acm_certificate.cert_api.domain_validation_options.*.resource_record_value, count.index)]
  ttl     = 60
}

resource "aws_route53_record" "api-a" {
  name    = aws_apigatewayv2_domain_name.api.domain_name
  type    = "A"
  zone_id = aws_route53_zone.api.zone_id

  alias {
    name                   = aws_apigatewayv2_domain_name.api.domain_name_configuration[0].target_domain_name
    zone_id                = aws_apigatewayv2_domain_name.api.domain_name_configuration[0].hosted_zone_id
    evaluate_target_health = false
  }
}

resource "aws_apigatewayv2_domain_name" "api" {
  domain_name = var.api_domain

  domain_name_configuration {
    certificate_arn = aws_acm_certificate.cert_api.arn
    endpoint_type   = "REGIONAL"
    security_policy = "TLS_1_2"
  }
}
```

Comment: Do you actually own the domain, did you buy it via AWS, transferred it or delegated DNS to your hosted zone?

Comment: purchased from goDaddy, I dont want to transfer it to AWS, I want the flexibility to change cloud providers quickly, delegated DNS to my hosted zone @luk2302

Comment: Can you properly e.g. `dig` to your domain, does the DNS delegation actually work? The validation probably times out because it cannot reach the cname you created because the delegation is faulty.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If the hosted zone is destroyed and re-provisioned, new name server records are associated with the new hosted zone. However,
the domain name might still have the previous name server records
associated with it.

If AWS Route 53 is used as the domain name registrar, head to *Route 53 > Registered domains > ${your-domain-name} > Add or edit name servers* and add the
newly associated name server records from the hosted zone to the registered domain.

Comment: i made the mistake and copied exactly the other way around.

It is important, als Blair said, to first create the hosted zone, then update the domain's name servers as it is written in the hosted zone.

Comment: Hey,
I am facing the same issue. What exactly needs to be done here to resolve this?
The order of resources in my terraform module is:
aws_route53_zone -->
aws_acm_certificate -->
aws_route53_record -->
aws_acm_certificate_validation

Comment: @AbhishekTyagi in the AWS Console, check that the NS records for your hosted zone match the name servers that are associated with the registered domains.